# Remove names from Json Encode

Tags: php, arrays, json

Currently my JSON outputs from the following PHP:

```
$data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                    'thumb'       => $image,
                    'name'        => $result['name'],
                    'description' => $desc,
                    'price'       => $price,
                    'special'     => $special,
                    'tax'         => $tax,  
                );
```

And with this (`$products = json_encode ($data['products']);`) produces the following:

```
[{"product_id":"28",
"thumb":"x",
"name":"name",
"description":"abc",
"price":"$123.00",
"special":false,
"tax":"$100.00"}]
```

Is it possible to delete the names without modifying the php "`$data['products'][] = array();`"? I am trying to achieve:

```
 ["28",
   "x",
   "name",
   "abc",
   "$123.00",
   false,
   "$100.00"]
```

First time ever using JSON encode so any other advice would be awesome!

Comment: encode only value like $json = json_encode(array_values($data['products']));

Comment: what you are trying to achieve is not valid json.  Highly unlikely the builtin `json_encode` would produce that under any circumstance.

Comment: `[{"28", "x", /*...*/}]` is invalid JSON. You could do `[["28", "x", /*...*/]]` but you probably just want `["28", "x", /*...*/]` (unless, of course, there are multiple of these).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_map` to loop thru your array and use `array_values` as callback function to convert the associative array to simple array

```
$arr = array_map('array_values', $data['products'] );
$products = json_encode ($arr);
```

This will result to:

```
[["28","x","name","abc","$123.00",false,"$100.00"]]
```

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/ffjdm6)

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Fantastic!

Comment: Happy to help @Beth

Comment: @Beth: I thought you just wanted *one* level (`[...]`), not two (`[[...]]`). That's what you show in the edited question.

Comment: @Eddie when passing this to javascript do I need to do it another way? I'm getting Undefined variable. Before I was using in javascript: var products = <?php echo json_encode($products); ?>;

Comment: @Beth Is `$products` defined? Maybe you need `var products = <?php echo json_encode($arr);?>;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to get the values of the first/only entry in `$data['products']`, and then encode that:

```
$json = json_encode(array_values($data['products'][0]));
```

That produces

```
["28","x","name","abc","$123.00",false,"$100.00"]
```

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/qtNOq5)